# How to wait for the calling of request.finish() in Python/Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

In my python file I have two handler classes: MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler) and WebSocketHandler(tornado.web.WebSocketHandler). In the MainHandler class I do the following code in the get method:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   #some code
   def get(self):
      #some code
      mainHandler_dict[chan] = self
      await self.finish() #line of code that would do the waiting somehow
```

So I store the request in a global dictionary so I can call `request.write()` and `request.finish()` in the `on_message` method of the WebSocketHandler class:

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
   def on_message(self, message):
      #some code 
      request.write(body)
      request.finish()
```

I get the "request" variable from the global dictionary and try to call write(), but the following error occurs: `RuntimeError: Cannot write() after finish()`

I think `finish()` is being automatically called after the end of the get method in the MainHandler class.
So is there a way for the requestHandler to keep on "waiting" while I don't call the `request.finish()` somewhere through the file?

Comment: Well, *you're* calling `finish` very explicitly, and then wait on its return value.

Comment: But the problem is that when I try to write in ```request.write(body)```, I think the handler already called ```finish()``` itself. My line ```request.finish()``` never executes.

Comment: No, *you call `finish` here:* `await self.finish()`. You call it. That's when the request finishes.

Comment: If I don't do that line, I still get the same error. That line is my attempt to kinda wait for it being called somewhere else. I guess it doesn't work this way.

Comment: You need to keep the function from finishing by `await`ing something that won't let it finish until it has the value. I've posted a solution below.

Comment: Yes, I've seen your solution and it works in my example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably handle this the other way around; don't store "the request", try to keep it alive somehow, and write to it from elsewhere, but rather let the request handler wait for the value you need to become available. E.g.:

```
class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        value = await magic()
        self.write(value)
```

Now, how to handle the "`magic`" part depends a bit where that value comes from and what's at your disposal, but let's illustrate with a simple `Future`:

```
async def get(self):
    futures[chan] = asyncio.Future()
    value = await futures[chan]
    self.write(value)
```

And elsewhere:

```
futures[chan].set_result(42)
```